# Is there a library in Java for SQL like string searches?

Tags: java, regex, database, string, search

I'm looking for an api/method/framework where I can compare strings. One is a string stored on the server whereas the other is a string given by user input.

For example:
 Stored String : "Login"
 User input : "login" "log in" "lOG IN" or any such permutation.

I'm using java in spring mvc (making a webapp). the server is getting a string from the user and then looks for a string similar to the given string and returns the found records.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are the strings stored on the server side?

Comment: `I need my code to return the database string : "Login" for all such scenarios. I'm not using a database`..what  ????

Comment: The strings are stored in files, which are then parsed and stored into models. Due to some constraints I can't use a database.

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't make any sense. More details would be needed before anybody could begin to help. Like, what sort of server, how do the two strings meet, are they being compared on the server or on the client, is this a web application, thick client, thin client... IOW, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: *Any* possible permutation?! Why wouldn't you just convert everything to a single case, strip whitespace, and compare?

Comment: @suresh: What i meant to say was that when I do a search with any of the user input terms, I should be able to return the string stored in my file. i.e. I shouldn't need an "exact" string to search for something in my files

Comment: If the user inputs : "Login Error" and in the files if I have "Login problems". I want my program to return the record(s) which points to login problems.

Comment: You should be thinking in re-writting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your data size is small (< a few MB), you probably want something  like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), which can be used to index and search large document sets, and can do fuzzy searches using Levenshtein distance and other algorithms for similarity matches.